# d3 not displaying initial data to bound rects

Tags: d3.js, data-binding

I have an initial array of object which is my data. A function called `render()` is called which should first display rectangles bound to this data. But I am not seeing any rectangles.

Then if any of these rectangles is clicked a function `removeElement` is called, which removes that rectangle's data from the array and then calls `render()` and executes it using the new data.

If the svg is clicked on anywhere a new data element is added to the data, and again render is called which should display the rectangles again according to the new data.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  /*.active {
    stroke: #000;
    stroke-width: 2px;
  }*/

  svg {
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
</style>
<svg width="800" height="300"></svg>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var margin = {
      top: 20,
      right: 20,
      bottom: 20,
      left: 20
    },
    width = 840 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 640 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  var svg = d3.select("svg");

  var data = [{
    x: 100
  }, {
    x: 300
  }, {
    x: 400
  }, {
    x: 600
  }];

  var ind = 0;
  var groove = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "groove_group");

  groove.append("rect")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 150)
    .attr("rx", 2)
    .attr("ry", 2)
    .attr("height", 6)
    .attr("width", width)
    .style("fill", "grey");

  groove.append("rect")
    .attr("x", 2)
    .attr("y", 152)
    .attr("rx", 2)
    .attr("ry", 2)
    .attr("height", 2)
    .attr("width", 796)
    .style("fill", "black");

  render();

  function render() {
    // create group
    var group = svg.selectAll(null)
      .data(data, function(d) {
        return d.x
      });

    group.exit().remove();

    group.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "group")
      .call(d3.drag()
        .on("start", dragstarted)
        .on("drag", dragged)
        .on("end", dragended))
      .on("click", removeElement);

    group.append("rect")
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return d.x;
      })
      .attr("y", 100)
      .attr("height", 100)
      .attr("width", 15)
      .style("fill", "lightblue")
      .attr('id', function(d, i) {
        return 'handle_' + i;
      })
      .attr("rx", 6)
      .attr("ry", 6)
      .attr("stroke-width", 2)
      .attr("stroke", "black");

    group.append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d, i) {
        if (i == 0) { // first element
          return ((data[i].x / 2));
        } else {
          return (data[i].x - (data[i].x - data[i - 1].x) / 2);
        }
      })
      .attr("y", 100)
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .style("fill", "black")
      .attr('id', function(d, i) {
        return 'text_' + i;
      })
      .text(function(d, i) {
        if (i == 0) { // first set
          return i + ": " + (data[i].x) + "m";
        } else {
          return i + ": " + ((data[i].x - data[i - 1].x)) + "m";
        }
      });
    
  }
  svg.on("click", function() {
    var coords = d3.mouse(this);

    getPosition(ind, coords[0]);

    render();

  });

  function dragstarted(d) {
    d3.select(this).raise().classed("active", true);
  }

  function dragged(d, i) {
    if (i == 0) {
      d3.select("#text_" + i)
        .attr("x", d.x = (d3.event.x / 2))
        .text(function(d) {
          return i + " " + d3.event.x
        });
      d3.select("#text_" + (i + 1))
        .attr("x", d.x = d3.event.x + ((data[i + 1].x - d3.event.x) / 2))
        .text(function(d) {
          return (i + 1) + " " + (data[i + 1].x - d3.event.x) + "m"
        });
      d3.select(this).select("rect")
        .attr("x", d.x = d3.event.x);
    } else if (i == data.length - 1) {
      d3.select("#text_" + i)
        .attr("x", d.x = (d3.event.x - data[i - 1].x) / 2 + data[i - 1].x)
        .text(function(d) {
          return i + ": " + (d3.event.x - data[i - 1].x) + "m"
        });
      d3.select("#text_" + (i + 1))
        .attr("x", d.x = d3.event.x + (width - d3.event.x) / 2)
        .text(function(d) {
          return (i + 1) + ": " + (width - d3.event.x) + "m"
        });
      d3.select(this).select("rect")
        .attr("x", d.x = d3.event.x);
    } else {
      d3.select("#text_" + i)
        .attr("x", d.x = d3.event.x - ((d3.event.x - data[i - 1].x) / 2))
        .text(function(d) {
          return i + ": " + (d3.event.x - data[i - 1].x) + "m"
        });
      d3.select("#text_" + (i + 1))
        .attr("x", d.x = d3.event.x + ((data[i + 1].x - d3.event.x) / 2))
        .text(function(d) {
          return (i + 1) + ": " + (data[i + 1].x - d3.event.x) + "m"
        });
      d3.select(this).select("rect")
        .attr("x", d.x = d3.event.x);
    }
  }

  function dragended(d) {
    d3.select(this)
      .classed("active", false);
  }

  function removeElement(d, i) {
    d3.event.stopPropagation();
   
    data = data.filter(function(e) {
      return e != d;
    });
    d3.select(this)
      .remove();

    render();
   
  }

  function getPosition(ind, coords) {
    if (coords[0] > data[ind].x) {
      getPosition(++ind);
    } else {
      data.splice(1, 0, {
        x: coords
      });
    }
  }
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at `group`...

```
var group = svg.selectAll(null)
    .data(data, function(d) {
        return d.x
    });
```

... you'll see that it is just an "update" selection. There is **no** SVG `<g>` element being appended here. Thus, this...

```
group.append("rect")
    //etc...
```

Has no effect.

**Solution**: Use a `merge()` function or a proper enter selection:

```
var groupEnter = group.enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "group");

groupEnter.append("rect")
    //etc...
```

Here is the updated code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  /*.active {
    stroke: #000;
    stroke-width: 2px;
  }*/

  svg {
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
</style>
<svg width="800" height="300"></svg>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var margin = {
      top: 20,
      right: 20,
      bottom: 20,
      left: 20
    },
    width = 840 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 640 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  var svg = d3.select("svg");

  var data = [{
    x: 100
  }, {
    x: 300
  }, {
    x: 400
  }, {
    x: 600
  }];

  var ind = 0;
  var groove = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "groove_group");

  groove.append("rect")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 150)
    .attr("rx", 2)
    .attr("ry", 2)
    .attr("height", 6)
    .attr("width", width)
    .style("fill", "grey");

  groove.append("rect")
    .attr("x", 2)
    .attr("y", 152)
    .attr("rx", 2)
    .attr("ry", 2)
    .attr("height", 2)
    .attr("width", 796)
    .style("fill", "black");

  render();

  function render() {
    // create group
    var group = svg.selectAll(null)
      .data(data, function(d) {
        return d.x
      });

    group.exit().remove();

    var groupEnter = group.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "group");
      
    groupEnter.call(d3.drag()
        .on("start", dragstarted)
        .on("drag", dragged)
        .on("end", dragended))
      .on("click", removeElement);

    groupEnter.append("rect")
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return d.x;
      })
      .attr("y", 100)
      .attr("height", 100)
      .attr("width", 15)
      .style("fill", "lightblue")
      .attr('id', function(d, i) {
        return 'handle_' + i;
      })
      .attr("rx", 6)
      .attr("ry", 6)
      .attr("stroke-width", 2)
      .attr("stroke", "black");

    groupEnter.append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d, i) {
        if (i == 0) { // first element
          return ((data[i].x / 2));
        } else {
          return (data[i].x - (data[i].x - data[i - 1].x) / 2);
        }
      })
      .attr("y", 100)
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .style("fill", "black")
      .attr('id', function(d, i) {
        return 'text_' + i;
      })
      .text(function(d, i) {
        if (i == 0) { // first set
          return i + ": " + (data[i].x) + "m";
        } else {
          return i + ": " + ((data[i].x - data[i - 1].x)) + "m";
        }
      });
    
  }
  svg.on("click", function() {
    var coords = d3.mouse(this);

    getPosition(ind, coords[0]);

    render();

  });

  function dragstarted(d) {
    d3.select(this).raise().classed("active", true);
  }

  function dragged(d, i) {
    if (i == 0) {
      d3.select("#text_" + i)
        .attr("x", d.x = (d3.event.x / 2))
        .text(function(d) {
          return i + " " + d3.event.x
        });
      d3.select("#text_" + (i + 1))
        .attr("x", d.x = d3.event.x + ((data[i + 1].x - d3.event.x) / 2))
        .text(function(d) {
          return (i + 1) + " " + (data[i + 1].x - d3.event.x) + "m"
        });
      d3.select(this).select("rect")
        .attr("x", d.x = d3.event.x);
    } else if (i == data.length - 1) {
      d3.select("#text_" + i)
        .attr("x", d.x = (d3.event.x - data[i - 1].x) / 2 + data[i - 1].x)
        .text(function(d) {
          return i + ": " + (d3.event.x - data[i - 1].x) + "m"
        });
      d3.select("#text_" + (i + 1))
        .attr("x", d.x = d3.event.x + (width - d3.event.x) / 2)
        .text(function(d) {
          return (i + 1) + ": " + (width - d3.event.x) + "m"
        });
      d3.select(this).select("rect")
        .attr("x", d.x = d3.event.x);
    } else {
      d3.select("#text_" + i)
        .attr("x", d.x = d3.event.x - ((d3.event.x - data[i - 1].x) / 2))
        .text(function(d) {
          return i + ": " + (d3.event.x - data[i - 1].x) + "m"
        });
      d3.select("#text_" + (i + 1))
        .attr("x", d.x = d3.event.x + ((data[i + 1].x - d3.event.x) / 2))
        .text(function(d) {
          return (i + 1) + ": " + (data[i + 1].x - d3.event.x) + "m"
        });
      d3.select(this).select("rect")
        .attr("x", d.x = d3.event.x);
    }
  }

  function dragended(d) {
    d3.select(this)
      .classed("active", false);
  }

  function removeElement(d, i) {
    d3.event.stopPropagation();
   
    data = data.filter(function(e) {
      return e != d;
    });
    d3.select(this)
      .remove();

    render();
   
  }

  function getPosition(ind, coords) {
    if (coords[0] > data[ind].x) {
      getPosition(++ind);
    } else {
      data.splice(1, 0, {
        x: coords
      });
    }
  }
</script>
```

PS: Your code still have a lot of problems (and I can foresee future questions here)... This answer is dealing **only** with the main issue regarding the "enter" selection.