# d3 not updating rectangles bound to data correctly

Tags: d3.js, updates

I have rectangles bound to an array of data called data. When I click the svg, the function removeElement is called. This function removes the element related to that rectangle from data. Then is calls the function render().

The problem is that the previous rectangles are not removed. So the render() function is not updating correctly.

After clicking on a rect and removing it, if I drag another rect, it can be seen that there is still a rect underneath.

And a similar related issue is that I have to double click on rects to remove them. Not sure why that is.

Here is the snippet (so-called snippet, actually the full code)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  /*.active {
    stroke: #000;
    stroke-width: 2px;
  }*/

  svg {
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
</style>
<svg width="800" height="300"></svg>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var margin = {
      top: 20,
      right: 20,
      bottom: 20,
      left: 20
    },
    width = 840 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 640 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  var svg = d3.select("svg");

  var data = [{
    x: 100
  }, {
    x: 300
  }, {
    x: 400
  }, {
    x: 600
  }];

  var ind = 0;
  var groove = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "groove_group");

  groove.append("rect")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 150)
    .attr("rx", 2)
    .attr("ry", 2)
    .attr("height", 6)
    .attr("width", width)
    .style("fill", "grey");

  groove.append("rect")
    .attr("x", 2)
    .attr("y", 152)
    .attr("rx", 2)
    .attr("ry", 2)
    .attr("height", 2)
    .attr("width", 796)
    .style("fill", "black");

  render();

  function render() {
    // create group
    var group = svg.selectAll(null)
      .data(data, function(d) {
        return d.x
      });

    group.exit().remove();

    var groupEnter = group.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "group");

    groupEnter.call(d3.drag()
        .on("start", dragstarted)
        .on("drag", dragged)
        .on("end", dragended))
      .on("click", removeElement);

    groupEnter.append("rect")
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return d.x;
      })
      .attr("y", 100)
      .attr("height", 100)
      .attr("width", 15)
      .style("fill", "lightblue")
      .attr('id', function(d, i) {
        return 'handle_' + i;
      })
      .attr("rx", 6)
      .attr("ry", 6)
      .attr("stroke-width", 2)
      .attr("stroke", "black");

    groupEnter.append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d, i) {
        if (i == 0) { // first element
          return ((data[i].x / 2));
        } else {
          return (data[i].x - (data[i].x - data[i - 1].x) / 2);
        }
      })
      .attr("y", 100)
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .style("fill", "black")
      .attr('id', function(d, i) {
        return 'text_' + i;
      })
      .text(function(d, i) {
        if (i == 0) { // first set
          return i + ": " + (data[i].x) + "m";
        } else {
          return i + ": " + ((data[i].x - data[i - 1].x)) + "m";
        }
      });

  }
  svg.on("click", function() {
    var coords = d3.mouse(this);

    getPosition(ind, coords[0]);

    render();

  });

  function dragstarted(d) {
    d3.select(this).raise().classed("active", true);
  }

  function dragged(d, i) {
    if (i == 0) {
      d3.select("#text_" + i)
        .attr("x", d.x = (d3.event.x / 2))
        .text(function(d) {
          return i + " " + d3.event.x
        });
      d3.select("#text_" + (i + 1))
        .attr("x", d.x = d3.event.x + ((data[i + 1].x - d3.event.x) / 2))
        .text(function(d) {
          return (i + 1) + " " + (data[i + 1].x - d3.event.x) + "m"
        });
      d3.select(this).select("rect")
        .attr("x", d.x = d3.event.x);
    } else if (i == data.length - 1) {
      d3.select("#text_" + i)
        .attr("x", d.x = (d3.event.x - data[i - 1].x) / 2 + data[i - 1].x)
        .text(function(d) {
          return i + ": " + (d3.event.x - data[i - 1].x) + "m"
        });
      d3.select("#text_" + (i + 1))
        .attr("x", d.x = d3.event.x + (width - d3.event.x) / 2)
        .text(function(d) {
          return (i + 1) + ": " + (width - d3.event.x) + "m"
        });
      d3.select(this).select("rect")
        .attr("x", d.x = d3.event.x);
    } else {
      d3.select("#text_" + i)
        .attr("x", d.x = d3.event.x - ((d3.event.x - data[i - 1].x) / 2))
        .text(function(d) {
          return i + ": " + (d3.event.x - data[i - 1].x) + "m"
        });
      d3.select("#text_" + (i + 1))
        .attr("x", d.x = d3.event.x + ((data[i + 1].x - d3.event.x) / 2))
        .text(function(d) {
          return (i + 1) + ": " + (data[i + 1].x - d3.event.x) + "m"
        });
      d3.select(this).select("rect")
        .attr("x", d.x = d3.event.x);
    }
  }

  function dragended(d) {
    d3.select(this)
      .classed("active", false);
  }

  function removeElement(d, i) {
    d3.event.stopPropagation();

    data = data.filter(function(e) {
      return e != d;
    });
    d3.select(this)
      .remove();

    render();

  }

  function getPosition(ind, coords) {
    if (coords[0] > data[ind].x) {
      getPosition(++ind);
    } else {
      data.splice(1, 0, {
        x: coords
      });
    }
  }
</script>
```

This question follows on from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46574674/d3-not-displaying-initial-data-to-bound-rects).

Comment: This is probably my fault: `selectAll(null)` is something that I often do in "enter" selections. In one of your past questions, I don't remember which one anymore, I used `selectAll(null)` and then you kept it in your code, repeating the pattern... However, here you have an "update" selection! So, the first line of the `render()` function should be: `var group = svg.selectAll(".group")`.

Comment: By the way, if you want to understand why I use `selectAll(null)`, have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46147231/5768908

Comment: That works great, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your `.exit()` is not working and hence your old elements are still visible after updates is because in your data join `.data()` you are doing `.selectAll(null)`.

When doing the data join d3 looks at all the existing elements based on your selector and then appends any elements needed in addition to what's already there or the other way around removes any that are not needed anymore. 
Based on your code selecting `null` d3 can't find any existing elements. It should work fine by changing it to `.selectAll('.group')`

Comment: I have just noticed that the last rect can't be dragged after another is clicked on and removed. Why might this be? Thanks